# Simulations using correlated random numbers from Multivariate Normal and fat-tailed distributions

Tags: r, finance, multivariate-distribution

This question makes use of the LaplacesDemon package in R, but it is *not* a coding question, so I believe this is the most appropriate forum.

First, the unsurprising results. I generate k correlated random numbers from each of the multivariate normal and laplace distributions. I take a weighted sum of each, where weights are usually around 0.05 and the sum of the weights is always exactly 1, so that k is, on average, about 20. I do this n times using rmvn and rmvl. Mean is 0 and dependence structure, S, uses the same covariance matrix for both the MV normal and MV laplace distributions. Covariance comes from a historical stream of numbers for each of the k=20 variables. After the n runs ( say, 1 million or so), I create a histogram of the results. The area on both the left and right tails of the MV Laplace simulation are consistently larger than that of the MV normal simulation. Specifically, the values representing a 2 standard deviation event are higher for the MV Laplace. So far so good for me.

Now the surprising part. If I extend this study further by first, for each of the k variables take the weighted sum of a run from each run of rmvl and rmvn say, m times( where m is around 250) and geometrically compound those results, and record the maximum peak-to-trough decline of the geometrically linked series and do this same procedure n times and create a histogram representing each of the n peak-to-trough values, I do not consistently get a larger 2 standard deviation value for the peak-to-trough values coming from MV laplace as compared to MV normal. I am wondering if there is something from the central limit theorem that I am missing that might explain this, or some other phenomenon.

For what it is worth, these random numbers represent the returns of stocks, hence the need for geometrically linking return streams to get maximum peak-to-trough declines in what amounts to a portfolio of stocks (hence the weighted sum of 1). This study assumes the portfolio is rebalanced to the initial weights on each of the m x n runs. Please advise.

*updated with code here*

```
library(tidyquant) 
library(magrittr) 
library(tibbletime) 
library(scales)
library(QRM)
library(LaplacesDemon)


n <- 20  #number of variables
A <- matrix(rnorm(n^3)/100, ncol=n) #normally distributed numbers 
covM <- cov(A)  #arbitrary covariance matrix among the n number of variables

NumSims <- 1000  #number of times to measure maximum peak-to-trough declines of compounded sampled return series. See maxDrawdown function
NDays <- 252 #number of trading days per year; the sampled returns are weighted each day and compounded NDays number of times

#Multiperiod return simulations
sample_mvlaplace_ts <- NULL
sample_mvnormal_ts <- NULL

for  (i in 1:NumSims) {

  #mv laplace returns generator
  sample_mvlaplace_ts_temp <- (
    LaplacesDemon::rmvl(NDays,
                        rep(0,nrow(covM)), covM)) 

  #mv normal returns generator
  sample_mvnormal_ts_temp <- (
    LaplacesDemon::rmvn(NDays,
                        rep(0, nrow(covM)), covM)) 


  sample_mvlaplace_ts[[i]] <- sample_mvlaplace_ts_temp


  sample_mvnormal_ts[[i]] <- sample_mvnormal_ts_temp}

#Create a list of the list of matrices 
#[[simulation type]] [[simulation number]]

sample_ts <- list(
  "sample_mvlaplace_ts"=sample_mvlaplace_ts,
  "sample_mvnormal_ts"=sample_mvnormal_ts)

#Create nSim_ts number of portfolio simulations 
#for each of the two simulation types

sims_ts_ports <- lapply(1:length(sample_ts), 
                        function (y) {
                          lapply(1:NumSims, function (x) {
                            sample_ts[[y]][[x]] %*% (rep(.05,n))})}) #equally weighted returns for each day (assumes n = 20)

#Unlist the list of matrices to a list of two 
#larger lists with each of the nSim_ts
#simulations combined.

sims_ts_ports_unlist <- lapply(1:length(sims_ts_ports),
                               function(z) {unlist(sims_ts_ports[[z]])})

#Turn the three larger lists back to a list of 2
#matrices of the correct dimension.

sims_ts_ports_unlist <- lapply(
  1:length(sims_ts_ports_unlist),
  function (q){matrix(sims_ts_ports_unlist[[q]],
                      nrow = NDays, ncol = NumSims)})

#Convert to a list of 2 xts objects with dummy 
#dates binded.

dummyDates <- lapply(sims_ts_ports_unlist,
                     function(a){
                       (order.by = as.Date(
                         1:nrow(sims_ts_ports_unlist[[1]])))})

sims_ts_ports_unlist_xts <- lapply(
  1:length(sims_ts_ports_unlist), 
  function(b){xts(sims_ts_ports_unlist[[b]],
                  order.by = dummyDates[[b]])})

#Distribution of nSim_ts number of drawdowns for each 
#of the two simulation types
#Uses maxDrawdown function from package 'PerformanceAnalytics' which is part of 'tidyquant'

sims_ts_ports_maxDrawdowns <-lapply(
  1:length(sims_ts_ports_unlist_xts),
  function(c) {
    maxDrawdown(sims_ts_ports_unlist_xts[[c]])})

#Giving each simulation of drawdowns a name for 
#each type of simulation. Can call each
#by $ for histograms

#rename for book display purposes

sims_tspmDD<- sims_ts_ports_maxDrawdowns

sims_tspmDD <- (list(
  "sim_drawdowns_Laplace" = sims_tspmDD[[1]],
  "sim_drawdowns_Normal" = sims_tspmDD[[2]]))

#Maximum drawdown analysis:
#Cutoff for the worst 5% of maximum drawdowns
#in the simulations

DD5_cut <- round(.95*NumSims,0) + 1

#Laplace simVar TS
DD5_laplace <- sims_tspmDD$sim_drawdowns_Laplace[
  order(sims_tspmDD$sim_drawdowns_Laplace)][
    DD5_cut:NumSims]
DD5_laplace_unconditional <- DD5_laplace[1]
DD5_laplace_conditional <- mean(DD5_laplace[1:(
  NumSims - DD5_cut + 1)])

#Normal simVar TS
DD5_normal <- sims_tspmDD$sim_drawdowns_Normal[
  order(sims_tspmDD$sim_drawdowns_Normal)][
    DD5_cut:NumSims]
DD5_normal_unconditional <- DD5_normal[1]
DD5_normal_conditional <- mean(DD5_normal[
  1:(NumSims - DD5_cut + 1)])

#Laplace
cat(
  "Unconditional MAXDD5:",
  round(DD5_laplace_unconditional,4), "|",
  "Conditional MAXDD5:",
  round(DD5_laplace_conditional,4))

#Normal
cat(
  "Unconditional MAXDD5:",
  round(DD5_normal_unconditional,
        4), "|",
  "Conditional MAXDD5:",
  round(DD5_normal_conditional,4))
```

Comment: Could you write out what you are doing in "the surprising part" in math?  It's hard to follow, at least for me, as text.

Comment: jbowman - Given my limited latex knowledge, it might be easier if I just supply a working example. Let me know if this is sufficient.